How do I create a calculated field that pulls data at a shorter interval (e.g., data from last 30 minutes, 90 minutes or so)
I'm trying to create the a calculated field for Google Data Studio (Looker Studio). it's a pretty simple calculated field, I want to pull in data from the last 30 minutes, particularly users to produce an automated reports for my manager.
Google date range control doesn't have the option for last 30 minute/hour so I just had to create a custom calculated field but to no avail. it just keeps saying no data, even though the formula was correct (as checked by data studio).
DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME(), PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', Date hour and minute), MINUTE) <= 60

